# SQL Server: Getting string before the last occurrence '>'

Tags: sql-server

I have column called `assocname`.

Sample data:

```
1. FirstParty>Individual:2
2. FirstParty:3>FPRep:2>Individual
3. Incident>Vehicle:2>RegisteredOwner>Individual3
```

I want to get the string before the last occurrence '>'. Here is the result:

```
1. FirstParty
2. FirstParty:3>FPRep:2
3. Incident>Vehicle:2>RegisteredOwner
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Isn't there a regex solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT LEFT(assocname, LEN(assocname) - CHARINDEX('>',REVERSE(assocname)))
```

So we're reversing it, finding the first `'>'`, then subtracting that from the length to find how far that character is from the beginning. Then take all characters up to that point.